# How to initialize decoder's state when it has multiple layers?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I'm using PyTorch/Tensorflow to implement a `seq2seq` model.

When the encoder has `m` layers while the decoder has `n` layers, should one use only the state of the *last* encoder layer to initialize the state of the *first* decoder layer and keep *all* the states of layers above zeros?

Or, when `m == n`, should one use *all* states of the encoder to initialize the states of the *corresponding* layer of the decoder?

If the encoder(decoder) is bidirectional while the decoder(encoder) is not, how to initialize the hidden state of the decoder in this situation?